# MongoDB Geospatial query result not getting in order of Distance

Tags: geospatial, php-mongodb

I am new to mongodb, trying to fetch result from mongodb using geospatial.
With this [http://jamesroberts.name/blog/2012/03/12/mongodb-geospatial-query-example-in-php-with-distance-radius-in-miles-and-km/][1] reference, I created 2d indexer on my collection.

I am getting result but not getting in sorted order of Distance.
I tried $near operator also but it returns 100 documents. I want all result near by given location under given miles
Can anyone please help me to get data in sorted order of distance?

```
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://192.168.1.167" );
$dbname="mydb";
$collectionName="user";
$db = $connection->$dbname;
$collection = $db->$collectionName;

$lat="36.23304900"; 
$lon="-115.24228800"; 
$radius = 40;
$collection = $db->$collectionName;
$radiusOfEarth = 3956; //avg radius of earth in miles
$query = array('lnglat' =>array('$geoWithin' =>array('$centerSphere' =>array(array(floatval($lon), floatval($lat)), $radius/$radiusOfEarth))) ,'user_id' => "1234" ,'type'=>"my_type");

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$cursor = $collection->find($query);

$cursor->sort(array('distance' => -1));
```

Comment: Thanks kratos. I tried this also. It also does not working. Because in the result set I am not getting distance.

Comment: sorry I made  mistake. I forgot that "distance" only gets returned when you use geoNear. Why don' you just get the result set and then sort it yourself later?

Comment: The $geoWithin operator does not return sorted results. As a result MongoDB can return $geoWithin queries more quickly than geospatial $near or $nearSphere queries, which sort results. So in short use $near or $nearSphere so that you can get sorted results if you do not want to use my approach above.